# Metric and imperial units, are the calculations correct?

Tags: calculus, functions, real-numbers

I've been re-learning metric and imperial conversions and know the basic rules of:

1 ft = 0.3048 m

1 m = 3.2808 ft
    -
Metric = feet

Imperial = Metres

I've rounded them down to 0.304 and 3.28 for calculating.

Have I got the calculations correct for these questions?
A lorry measures 32 feet 6 inches. How long is it in metres?

32.6 ft x 0.304 m = 9.9104 m [rounded to 2 d.p. as 9.9 m]

and
A road prohibits vehicles over 2.1m wide from entering. What width in feet would a vehicle be, in equivalent feet?

I did this calculation:

2.1 m x 3.28 ft = 6.888 ft [rounded to 2 d.p. as 6.8 ft]

The vehicle would have to be over 6"8 to enter.

Also, what's the major difference between these numbers:

32.6ft

32ft 6 inches

6.6ft

6ft 6 inches

Does it matter how it's written when doing a calculation to ensure you get the correct answer?

In general, is the rule to multiply for larger units, divide for smaller units for this sort of calculation?

I would appreciate any advice on this just to make sure got things right.

Comment: 32 feet 6 inches is $32.5$ feet, not $32.6$. That's because a feet is 12 inches.

Comment: All looks fine to me. You units when converting from meters to feet should read $2.1 \text{m} \times 3.28 \text{ft} m^{-1} = 6.89 \text{ft}$ but I knew what you meant. The latter statements are a misuse of notation, since $32.6$ ft is not $32$ ft $6$inches. A similar misuse is used in the game of Cricket in that, for  $6$ balls per 'over;, sports writers write $3.2$ overs to mean $3$ overs and $2$ balls from the fourth over.